# Why does Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production) not appear

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to set up my notifications for firebase, and I have it set up already using a .p12 file, but i've been reading that is now recommended to start using the .p8 file which is the auth key, but when I go into my developer account for apple I don't see that option anywhere, nor do I even see an option to see "APNs Auth Key" in my certificates option

Answer (score 2):

I think now you can generate .p8 in Key section in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
[image]

[image]

press continue

[image]

press confirm

[image]

Now you can download your .p8 file.